# in Itext 5 my second page has far (white space) from my first page

Tags: java, android, pdf, itext, pdf-generation

I used Itext5 to create a PDF. Because the text is in Persian, I used a table to write. But now there is a big gap between the first and second paragraphs that I added to the project. I don't want this long distance. you can see my code an the pdf result below.

this is my result.

[I don't want this long distance.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ry4k0.png)

this is my code

```
  private void createPDF() throws FileNotFoundException {
        Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10, 10, 50, 36);

        try {

            String root = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString();
            File dir = new File(root + "/pdf");
            if (!dir.exists()) {
                dir.mkdirs();
            }
            String filename = "saeedsss.pdf";
            File file = new File(dir, filename);
            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
            PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, fOut);

            doc.open();
            Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
            BaseFont myFont = BaseFont.createFont("assets/font/XB Zar.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
            BaseFont myFont1 = BaseFont.createFont("assets/font/BLOTUSB.TTF", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
            com.itextpdf.text.Font paraFont = new com.itextpdf.text.Font(myFont, 20);
            com.itextpdf.text.Font paraFont1 = new com.itextpdf.text.Font(myFont1, 19);
            p.setFont(paraFont);
            p.add("سعید بیات پریدری ");
            p.add(Html.fromHtml("<b> محسن بیات </b> ", 0).toString());
            p.add("حسین بیات پریدری");
            Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph();
            p1.setFont(paraFont1);

            p1.add("صورتجلسه مجمع عمومی عادی بطور فوق العاده برای انتخاب مدیران و بازرسین ،روزنامه و تصویب تراز در شرکتهای سهامی خاص\n" +
                    "نام شرکت : …………...............………………\n" +
                    "شماره ثبت شرکت : …………………………                                  \n" +
                    "سرمایه ثبت شده : …………………………\n" +
                    "شناسه ملی : ......................................\n" +
                    "صورتجلسه مجمع عمومی عادی بطور فوق العاه شرکت ………… سهامی خاص ثبت شده به شماره …....…… در تاریخ …………… ساعت……… با حضور کلیه / اکثریت سهامداران در محل قانونی شرکت (اگر جلسه در محل دیگری غیر از محل قانونی شرکت تشکیل شده آدرس آن محل نوشته شود) تشکیل گردید. \n" +
                    "الف: در اجرای ماده 101 لایحه اصلاحی قانون تجارت: \n" +
                    "1ـ خانم/ آقای ………………………… به سمت رئیس جلسه \n" +
                    "2ـ خانم/ آقای ………………………… به سمت ناظر جلسه \n" +
                    "3ـ خانم/ آقای ………………………… به سمت ناظر جلسه \n" +
                    "4ـ خانم/ آقای………………………… به سمت منشی جلسه انتخاب شدند. \n" +
                    "ب: در خصوص دستور جلسه، 1ـ انتخاب مدیران 2ـ انتخاب بازرسین 3ـ انتخاب روزنامه کثیرالانتشار 4ـ تصویب ترازنامه حساب سود و زیان به شرح ذیل اتخاذ تصمیم شد. \n" +
                    "ب : 1ـ اعضای هیات مدیره عبارتند از خانم/آقای ………. به شماره ملی …………………… خانم/آقای …….. به شماره ملی …………………… خانم/آقای ……….. به شماره ملی ……………………  برای مدت دو سال انتخاب و با امضاء ذیل صورتجلسه قبولی خود را اعلام می دارند. مجمع تصویب نمود در اجرای ماده 124 لایحه اصلاحی قانون تجارت میتواند رئیس هیئت مدیره و مدیر عامل یک نفر باشد.\n" +
                    "ب ـ 2ـ با رعایت ماده 147 لایحه اصلاحی قانون تجارت خانم / آقای ………..  به شماره ملی ……………… به سمت بازرس اصلی خانم / آقای …………. به شماره ملی …………………  به سمت بازرس علی البدل برای مدت یک سال مالی انتخاب شدند. \n" +
                    "ب ـ 3ـ روزنامه کثیرالانتشار ………………………… جهت نشر آگهی های شرکت انتخاب شد.\n" +
                    "ب ـ4ـ پس از قرائت گزارش بازرس قانونی ترازنامه و حساب سود و زیان شرکت منتهی به سال...................... مورد تصویب قرار گرفت. \n" +
                    "ج: اینجانبان اعضاء هیات مدیره و بازرسین ضمن قبولی سمت خود اقرار می نمائیم که هیچگونه سوء پیشینه کیفری نداشته و ممنوعیت اصل 141 قانون اساسی و مواد 111 و147 لایحه اصلاحی قانون تجارت را نداریم .\n" +
                    "د: به خانم / آقای ………………………… احدی از سهامداران یا احدی از مدیران یا وکیل رسمی شرکت وکالت داده می شود که ضمن مراجعه به اداره ثبت شرکت ها نسبت به ثبت صورتجلسه و پرداخت حق الثبت و امضاء ذیل دفاتر ثبت اقدام نماید.\n" +
                    "امضاء هیات رئیسه:  رئیس جلسه ……...........…    ناظر جلسه ………………     ناظرجلسه………………\n" +
                    "منشی جلسه ........................\n" +
                    "امضا اعضای هیئت مدیره : \n" +
                    "1 ـ ……………………   2 ـ ……………………   3ـ ……………………    4 ـ  ……………………\n" +
                    "امضاء بازرسین: \t \t             بازرس اصلی\t                    بازرس علی البدل:\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "\n ");

            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(p);
            PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell(p1);

            cell.setBorder(0);
            cell2.setBorder(0);

            table.getKeepTogether();
            cell2.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED);
            cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            cell.setRunDirection(PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL);
            cell2.setRunDirection(PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL);
            cell.setPaddingBottom(20);
            cell2.setLeading(20f, 0f);
            table.getKeepTogether();
            table.addCell(cell);
            table.addCell(cell2);

            table.getKeepTogether();
            doc.add(table);


        } catch (DocumentException de) {
            Log.e("PDFCreator", "DocumentException:" + de);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("PDFCreator", "ioException:" + e);
        } finally {

            doc.close();

        }

    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please paste your code as text into your post. You can edit your post to do so.

Comment: In your code you don't add anything to the PDF. Furthermore, what class is `Html`? It's not an iText class.

Comment: I edited my question can you help me?

Comment: I've not had to deal with such layout details myself, so I don't have a working solution up my sleeve. Some hints, though:  (1) your `table.getKeepTogether()` calls essentially do nothing, they return a value which your code immediately ignores. You probably wanted to use `table.setKeepTogether` with `true` or `false`. (2) Another method to try is `table.setSplitLate` with `true` or `false`. (3) Yet another approach would be add several `Paragraph` objects to `cell2` each with just one line instead of that single `p1` containing all those lines.

Comment: (4) Or, of course, use one cell per line.

Comment: dear mlk thank you.